# Multi Threading For getting links from Webbrowser1.Document

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, browser, hyperlink

The problem is that multi threading is not working properly for getting links from webbrowser1.document.links. How can I solve this problem?

```
Public Class Form1


Dim thread1 As System.Threading.Thread

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    thread1 = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf GetLinks)
    thread1.Start()

End Sub
Private Sub GetLinks()
    For i As Integer = 0 To WebBrowser1.Document.Links.Count - 1
        If TextBox1.Text.Length > 0 Then
            TextBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine & WebBrowser1.Document.Links(i).ToString
        Else
            TextBox1.Text = WebBrowser1.Document.Links(i).ToString

        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("www.google.com")
    Me.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? or getting no data? or the textBox is not updated?

Comment: Did you try testing the code by running it in thread rather than starting a new thread? In other words, is the problem in GetLinks or is Getlinks not even being executed?

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a call to one of the controls on the form (in this case, TextBox1 and WebBrowser1) from another thread other than the main thread of the form. You need to use a delegate.

This will do the trick:

```
  Private _iLinks As Integer

    Dim thread1 As System.Threading.Thread

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
        _iLinks = WebBrowser1.Document.Links.Count
        thread1 = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf GetLinks)
        thread1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub GetLinks()
        For i As Integer = 0 To _iLinks - 1
             UpdateTextBoxDelegate(i)             
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub UpdateTextBox(ByVal iLink As Integer)
        If TextBox1.Text.Length > 0 Then
            TextBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine & WebBrowser1.Document.Links(iLink).ToString
        Else
            TextBox1.Text += WebBrowser1.Document.Links(iLink).InnerText.ToString()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Delegate Sub UpdateTextBoxCallback(ByVal iLink As Integer)

    Private Sub UpdateTextBoxDelegate(ByVal iLink As Integer)
        Try
            If Me.InvokeRequired Then
                Dim cb As New UpdateTextBoxCallback(AddressOf UpdateTextBox)
                Me.Invoke(cb, New Object() {iLink})
            Else
                UpdateTextBox(iLink)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("There was an error " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://stackoverflow.com/")
    End Sub
```

Comment: @user2573005 Np. If this worked for you could you mark it as the correct answer?